# How to implement the methods in the absence of instance variables and generics

Tags: java

I'm working on a project where I need to replace the old ExpFoo with a new ExpFoo.

An example would be an ExpFoo ((x * y) + (x * z)) is given and we have new IntFoo, 2, which will replace the Varfoo, x. And we have a PlusFoo (a + b), which will replace the Varfoo, y.

So the result will be: ((2 * (a + b) + (2 * z))

Here's how it looks on the Main class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExpFoo e1 = new IntFoo(1);
    ExpFoo e2 = new IntFoo(2);
    ExpFoo e5 = new IntFoo(5);
    ExpFoo x = new VarFoo("x");
    ExpFoo plus = new PlusFoo(e1, e2);
    ExpFoo times = new TimesFoo(e5, x);
    ExpFoo bigTimes = new TimesFoo(plus, times);

    ExpFoo[] exps = { e1, e2, e5, x, plus, times, bigTimes };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(exps));

    Replacement r = new Replacement();
    r.put(new VarFoo("x"), new PlusFoo(e1, e5));
    System.out.println(r);

    for (ExpFoo exp : exps) {
        System.out.println(exp + " has " + exp.numberOfNodes() + " nodes and after applying " + r  + " the value " + exp.computeValue(r));
    }

    ExpFoo ex1 = new PlusFoo(new TimesFoo(new VarFoo("x"), new VarFoo("y")),new TimesFoo(new VarFoo("x"), new VarFoo("z")));
    Replacement repl = new Replacement();
    repl.put(new VarFoo("x"), new IntFoo(2));
    repl.put(new VarFoo("y"), new PlusFoo(new VarFoo("a"), new VarFoo("b")));
    ExpFoo ex2 = ex1.applyReplacement(repl);
    System.out.println("ex1: " + ex1);
    System.out.println("ex2: " + ex2);

}
}
```

I have two issues:

1. I cannot get the values of times and bigTimes.
2. I cannot get applyReplacement(repl) to work.

For the first issue, I couldn't get the values of `ExpFoo times = new TimesFoo(e5, x);` and
    `ExpFoo bigTimes = new TimesFoo(plus, times);` to use `exp.computeValue(r)` because I couldn't work out on how to calculate 1 + 5 to 6.

All I've got was an exception that says: **UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot compute the value of a varfoo without a replacement!**

For times, it should return as  **(5 * x) has 3 nodes and after applying [x:=(1 + 5)] the value 30**
For bigTimes, it should return as **((1 + 2) * (5 * x)) has 7 nodes and after applying [x:=(1 + 5)] the value 90**

For the second issue, I'm having a problem with 
`ExpFoo ex2 = ex1.applyReplacement(repl);`

It returns an exception **TimesExpFoo cannot be cast to class com.company.VarFoo** I couldn't get it to work. 
It should return as **((2 * (a + b) + (2 * z))**

I'm not allowed to create instance variables to all the classes except Replacement.

I cannot use generics in all classes either.

Here's the illustration on how it works, the Replacement class is separated in all classes.

[UML image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO8Oq.jpg)

For the classes, this is what I've done so far.

Varfoo class:

```
import java.util.Set;

/**
* A VarFoo is a symbolic ExpFoo that stands for a value that has not yet
* been fixed. A VarFoo has a name of the format
* letter (letter | digit)^*
* (where '(letter | digit)^*' stands for 'a string of length 0 or more that
* contains only letters and digits').
* Here the class methods Character.isLetter(char) and
* Character.isLetterOrDigit(char) determine whether a character is
* a letter/a letter or a digit, respectively.
* Instances of this class are immutable.
*/
public class VarFoo implements ExpFoo {

/**
 * Name of this VarFoo. Non-null, of the format
 * <p>
 * letter (letter | digit)*
 */
private String name;

/**
 * Constructs a new VarFoo with the specified name.
 *
 * @param name must not be null; must be a String of the format letter
 *             (letter | digit)^*
 */

public VarFoo(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public int numberOfNodes() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public int computeValue() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot compute the value of a varfoo without a replacement!");
}

@Override
public int computeValue(Replacement repl) {
    //TODO;
}

@Override
public ExpFoo applyReplacement(Replacement s) {
    //TODO
}

@Override
public boolean isVarFooFree() {
    // TODO
    return true;
}

@Override
public Set<VarFoo> getVarfoo() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void collectVarfoo(Set<VarFoo> vars) {
    for (char c : name.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)){
            vars.add(new VarFoo(name));
        }
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * The method returns true if o is an instance of class VarFoo
 * whose name is equal to the name of this VarFoo; otherwise it
 * returns false.
 *
 * @return whether this VarFoo and Object o are equal
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) return false;
    if (!(o instanceof VarFoo))
        return false;
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    return name.equals(((VarFoo) o).name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;


}
}
```

Replacement class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
* A Replacement represents a mapping of finitely many VarFoo to
* ExpFoo. One can construct an empty Replacement, update a Replacement
* by adding/replacing/forgetting mappings of VarFoo to ExpFoo, and
* query Replacements for the value to which they map a varfoo, whether they
* have a mapping for a specific varfoo, and for a String representation.
*/
public class Replacement {

private Map<VarFoo, ExpFoo> replacementMap;

/**
 * Constructs an empty Replacement (i.e., a Replacement that does not
 * hold mappings for any varfoo(s).
 */
public Replacement() {
    replacementMap = new HashMap<>();
}

/* Mutators */

/**
 * Associates the specified ExpFoo with the specified Varfoo in this
 * Replacement. If the Replacement previously contained a mapping for the
 * Varfoo, the old ExpFoo is replaced.
 *
 * @param var the Varfoo with which exp is to be associated
 * @param exp the ExpFoo to which var is to be mapped
 * @return the ExpFoo to which var was mapped so far, or null if var did
 * not yet have a mapping in this Replacement
 * @throws NullPointerException if var or exp is null
 */
public ExpFoo put(VarFoo var, ExpFoo exp) {
    return replacementMap.put(var, exp);
}

/**
 * Forgets the mapping for the specified Varfoo. Does not modify this
 * Replacement if it does not have a mapping for the specified Varfoo.
 *
 * @param var the Varfoo for which we want to forget the mapping
 * @return whether a mapping for var was forgotten due to the method call
 * @throws NullPointerException may be thrown if var is null
 */
public boolean forget(VarFoo var) {
    if (var == null) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        replacementMap.clear();
        return true;
    }
}

/* Accessors */

/**
 * Returns the value to which the specified Varfoo is mapped, or null if
 * this Replacement contains no mapping for the specified Varfoo.
 *
 * @param var the Varfoo for which we want the corresponding ExpFoo to
 *            which it is mapped
 * @return the ExpFoo to which this Replacement maps var, or var if
 * this Replacement does not have a mapping for var
 * @throws NullPointerException may be thrown if var is null
 */
public ExpFoo get(VarFoo var) {
    return replacementMap.get(var);
}

/**
 * Returns whether this Replacement has an explicit mapping of var to an
 * ExpFoo.
 *
 * @param var the Varfoo for which we want to know if this Replacement
 *            has a mapping
 * @return whether this Replacement has an explicit mapping of var to an
 * ExpFoo
 * @throws NullPointerException may be thrown if the parameter is null
 */
public boolean hasMappingFor(VarFoo var) {
    return replacementMap.containsValue(var);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    for (Map.Entry<VarFoo, ExpFoo> ReplacementKey : replacementMap.entrySet()) {
        s = "[" + ReplacementKey.getKey() + ":=" + ReplacementKey.getValue() + "]";
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

ExpFoo class:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
* Basic interface for arithmetic ExpFoo. Implementations are expected to
* be immutable, i.e., after object creation, the object's state cannot change,
* and there are no mutator methods in any class that implements this interface.
*/
public interface ExpFoo {

/**
 * Computes the number of sub-ExpFoo of this ExpFoo (its "size").
 *
 * @return the number of nodes of this ExpFoo.
 */
int numberOfNodes();

/**
 * Computes the int value represented by this ExpFoo object. This
 * ExpFoo object must not contain Varfoos.
 *
 * @return the int value represented by this ExpFoo
 */
int computeValue();

/**
 * Computes the int value represented by this ExpFoo.
 *
 * @param repl
 *            to be used to assign values to this ExpFoo; must not be
 *            null
 * @return the int value represented by this ExpFoo
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException
 *             if the ExpFoo with repl applied to it still has
 *             Varfoo
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *             if s is null
 */
default int computeValue(Replacement repl) {
    ExpFoo specialised = applyReplacement(repl);
    return specialised.computeValue();
}

/**
 * Returns whether this ExpFoo is VarFoo-free, i.e., none of its
 * direct or indirect sub-ExpFoo is a VarFoo object.
 *
 * @return whether this ExpFoo is VarFoo-free, i.e., none of its
 *         direct or indirect sub-ExpFoo is a VarFoo object.
 */
boolean isVarFooFree();

/**
 * Returns the Set of Varfoo of this ExpFoo. The returned Set may be
 * modified.
 *
 * @return the Set of Varfoo of this ExpFoo
 */
default Set<VarFoo> getVarfoo() {
    Set<VarFoo> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    collectVarfoo(result);
    return result;
}

/**
 * Adds all Varfoo in this ExpFoo to vars
 *
 * @param vars
 *            Varfoo will be added here; parameter must not be null
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *             if vars is null
 */
void collectVarfoo(Set<VarFoo> vars);

/**
 * Applies a Replacement to this ExpFoo and returns the result.
 *
 * @param r
 *            a Replacement to be applied to this ExpFoo; must not be
 *            null
 * @return a version of this ExpFoo where all Varfoo have been
 *         replaced by the values stored in s for the Varfoo
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *             if s is null
 */
ExpFoo applyReplacement(Replacement r);
}
```

BinaryFoo class:

```
import java.util.Set;

/**
* Abstract class for ExpFoos with two direct subExpFoos. Provides an
* implementation for numberOfNodes() method. Instances of this class are immutable.
*/
public abstract class BinaryFoo implements ExpFoo {

/** the left subExpFoo; non-null */
private ExpFoo left;

/** the right subExpFoo; non-null */
private ExpFoo right;

/** String representation of the operator symbol; non-null */
private String operatorSymbol;

/**
 * Constructs a BinaryFoo with left and right as direct
 * subExpFoo and with operatorSymbol as the String representation of
 * the operator.
 *
 * @param left
 *            the left subExpFoo; non-null
 * @param right
 *            the right subExpFoo; non-null
 * @param operatorSymbol
 *            String representation of the operator symbol; non-null
 */
public BinaryFoo(ExpFoo left, ExpFoo right,
                 String operatorSymbol) {
    if (left == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Illegal null value for left!");
    }
    if (right == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Illegal null value for right!");
    }
    if (operatorSymbol == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException(
                "Illegal null value for operatorSymbol!");
    }
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.operatorSymbol = operatorSymbol;
}

/**
 * Getter for the left subExpFoo.
 *
 * @return the left subExpFoo
 */
public ExpFoo getLeft() {
    return left;
}

/**
 * Getter for the right subExpFoo.
 *
 * @return the right subExpFoo
 */
public ExpFoo getRight() {
    return right;
}

/**
 * Getter for the operator symbol.
 *
 * @return the operator symbol
 */
public String getOperatorSymbol() {
    return operatorSymbol;
}

@Override
public int numberOfNodes() {
    return 1 + left.numberOfNodes() + right.numberOfNodes();
}

@Override
public void collectVariables(Set<VarFoo> vars) {
    vars.add((VarFoo)left);
    vars.add((VarFoo)right);
}

@Override
public boolean isVarFooFree() {
    // TODO
    return false;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(" + left + " " + operatorSymbol + " " + right + ")";
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof BinaryFoo)) {
        return false;
    }
    BinaryFoo other = (BinaryFoo) o;
    // relies on instance variables being non-null
    return operatorSymbol.equals(other.operatorSymbol)
            && left.equals(other.left) && right.equals(other.right);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = (left == null) ? 0 : left.hashCode();
    result += (right == null) ? 0 : right.hashCode();
    return result;
}
}
```

TimesFoo class:

```
/**
* Represents an ExpFoo of the form e1 * e2.
* Instances of this class are immutable.
*/
public class TimesFoo extends BinaryFoo {

/**
 * Constructs a TimesFoo with left and right as direct
 * subExpFoo.
 */
public TimesFoo(ExpFoo left, ExpFoo right) {
    super(left, right, "*");
}

@Override
public int computeValue() {
    return getLeft().computeValue() * getRight().computeValue();
}

@Override
public int computeValue(Replacement subst) {
    return computeValue();
}

@Override
public ExpFoo applyReplacement(Replacement r) {
    ExpFoo e = s.get((VarFoo)getVarFoo());
    return e;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof TimesFoo)) {
        return false;
    }
    return super.equals(o);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return super.hashCode();
}
}
```

PlusFoo class:

```
/**
* Represents an ExpFoo of the form e1 + e2.
* Instances of this class are immutable.
*/
public class PlusFoo extends BinaryFoo {

/**
 * Constructs a PlusFoo with left and right as direct subExpFoos.
 *
 * @param left  the left subExpFoo; non-null
 * @param right the right subExpFoo; non-null
 */
public PlusFoo(ExpFoo left, ExpFoo right) {
    super(left, right, "+");
}

@Override
public int computeValue() {
    return getLeft().computeValue() + getRight().computeValue();
}

@Override
public ExpFoo applyReplacement(Replacement r) {
    ExpFoo e = s.get((VarFoo)getVarFoo());
    return e;
}

@Override
public int computeValue(Replacement repl) {
    return computeValue();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof PlusFoo)) {
        return false;
    }
    return super.equals(o);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return super.hashCode();
}
}
```

IntFoo class:

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

/**
* ExpFoo that represents an int value.
*/
public class IntFoo implements ExpFoo {

/**
 * Stores the encapsulated value.
 */
private int value;

/**
 * Constructs a new IntFoo encapsulating value.
 *
 * @param value to be encapsulated in this IntFoo
 */
public IntFoo(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

/**
 * @return the int value this IntFoo stands for
 */
public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

@Override
public int numberOfNodes() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public int computeValue(Replacement repl) {
    return computeValue();
}

@Override
public int computeValue() {
    return value;
}

@Override
public ExpFoo applyReplacement(Replacement r) {
    VarFoo var = new Variable(name); //error
    ExpFoo e = s.get(var);
    return e;
}

@Override
public boolean isVarFooFree() {
    // TODO
    return false;
}

@Override
public Set<VarFoo> getVarfoo() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void collectVarfoo(Set<VarFoo> vars) {

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "" + value;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) return false;
    if (!(o instanceof IntFoo))
        return false;
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    return value == (((IntFoo) o).value);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(value);
}
}
```

Comment: Is this a situation where you want to redefine a method without recompiling all the source?  How is the method entered?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Your question seems very broad and this might make it difficult for people to answer it. Please consider checking out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and editing your question accordingly, so that users have an easier time to understand the problem and can answer your questions.

Comment: I think you should look into recursive descent parsers.

Comment: @WJS It is entered through the Main class.

Comment: Have you considered just rewriting the class and loading it in via a class loader?  Then using reflection to invoke the new methods.

Comment: @WJS I'm not sure how that works.

Comment: Question is too long. I didn't read it all but i'm certain you don't need all that to demonstrate the problem

Comment: @Michael I guess so, should I delete this question then?

Comment: If you want to maximize your chances of getting an answer, you can edit it, taking into consideration [the advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Because of the way the stack overflow algorithm works, you are probably better off deleting it and asking a new question than editing though. Or you can leave it and hope that some kind soul will read the whole thing, but most people are lazy like I am.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, I'll try to be more specific. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem

> I cannot get the values of times and bigTimes.

the root cause is in `TimesFoo#computeValue`

```
@Override
    public int computeValue(Replacement subst) {
    return computeValue();
}
```

you are completely ignoring the replacement parameter in that method `subst` and just calling `computeValue()` so your variable is never going to be resolve, hence the error `UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot compute the value of a varfoo without a replacement!`

for the second one

> I cannot get applyReplacement(repl) to work.

the root cause is in `PlusFoo#applyReplacement`

```
@Override
    public ExpFoo applyReplacement(Replacement r) {
    return null;
}
```

you are just returning `null` there so that's what your getting. You need to apply the replacement recursively to the sub-expressions

Comment: I'll edit them so it will be appear to have that issue rather than returning null.

Comment: @kurono I don't get it, putting a //TODO there is not going to fix anything, you need to do a correct implamentation of the methods that I pointed in the answer

Comment: Apologies, I did try to reimplement it without //TODO

Answer (score 0):

This example is just a toy and not complete is some areas.  But it illustrates the power to dynamically load classes that have not been previous compiled into your application.

```
        try {
            Class<?> clas = getClass().getClassLoader()
                    .loadClass(
                            "junk.keep.streamsandLambdas.MyMethods");
            Object myMethods = clas.getConstructor()
                    .newInstance();
            Method[] methods = myMethods.getClass()
                    .getDeclaredMethods();
            System.out.println("Available methods:");
            for (Method m : methods) {
                System.out.println("  " + m.getName());
            }
            Method m  = myMethods.getClass().getMethod("expFoo", int.class, 
                         int.class, int.class);
            System.out.println("\nInvoking " + m.getName());

            int v = (int) m.invoke(myMethods, 10,20,30);
            System.out.println(v);
        } catch (Exception cnf) {
            cnf.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now place the following compiled class in the same package and location as your other classes.

```
      package your.package.name;

      public class MyMethods {

         public int expFoo(int x, int y, int z) {
             return (x*y) + (x * z);
         }

         public int plusFoo(int a, int b) {
             return a + b;
         }
      }
```

You can change the `MyMethods` contents and recompile without changing your main application. There is much more to this using class loaders and reflection. You can create special classes in their own location and define your own class loader to load them. I do not know if this will help your current requirement but it is still worth knowing about.